# Graceful handling of JQuery Ajax JSON errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have an Ajax save function to save employee data, and it returns a json object with the details of the save. These details are then display on the browser.

There are occasions however when my server side code might spit out some php errors or warnings(due to whatever reason). This server returns a bunch of unexpected php notice / warning / error messages **along with the json array**. This means that the employee save was could actually have been SUCCESSFUL. Such an example of a ajax return is below, notice it returns a successful save in the json array at the end.

```
Warning (2): Missing argument 3 for EmployeeControl::getByMerchantID(), called in /home/empcentral/public_html/demo/app/Controller/Component/BMComponent.php on line 98 and defined [APP/Model/EmployeeControl.php, line 198]
Notice (8): Undefined variable: merchant_id [APP/Model/EmployeeControl.php, line 203]
{"status":true,"failtype":"USER","message":"Employee successfully saved!","employeeid":"846"}
```

Because of the added PHP messages in addition to the json array,  Jquery is not able to parse the whole as a proper JSON array, hence it triggers the .fail() function.

My issue is actually being able to display appropriate messages to the user from the json array even in the event of a fail(). **Question: i'm not sure how to read the json array in the .fail() function because its garbled together with the php messages.**

This is my code that shows how it usually handles normal ajax returns without errors.

```
    $("#res_button").on("click", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $.post( "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Employee','action'=>'saveEmployee_ajax')); ?>", $( ".reservationform" ).serialize(), function() {
        }, "json")

        .done(function(data) {

            var respstatus = data.status; 
            var message = data.message;
            var failtype = data.failtype;
            var employeeid = data.employeeid;

            //Display Confirmation or Error messages to users
            if (respstatus === false) {
                $("#failureMessage").html(message);
                res_div_confirmdetails_to_res_div_failure();
            }

            if (respstatus === true) {
                $("#successMessage").html(message);
                $("#successEmployeeId").html(employeeid);
                res_div_confirmdetails_to_res_div_success();
            }

        })
        .fail(function(p1, p2, p3) {
            alert( "There was a problem saving the employee!" );
            alert(p1);
            alert(p2);
            alert(p3);
        })
        .always(function() {
            //alert( "finished (always)" );
        });
```

Comment: you may need to handle error in php script and send a status code to the ajax call back to resolve the status, success or fail

Comment: hi @buddhi i'm not sure how i would do that. The example return in my original post already returns a HTTP 200 OK Code. Its just a malformed json array triggering the fail() because of the PHP errors. Could you explain a little more how you might go about doing this?

Comment: handle the Missing argument 3 , Undefined variable: merchant_id

Comment: Production code should run with `error_reporting(0)` so that error messages aren't returned to the client. You have to check for errors in your code, and then add messages about them to your JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you should use try{}catch(){}.

Example:

```
var data = {"action":"someAction","id":"someID"};
$.post("urlToPostTo",data,function(data){
    try{
        result=$.parseJSON(data);
        //further actions with result object
    }catch(err){
       //some action to perform because the json could not be parsed.
    } 
});
```

You could then use regex or something else to look for errors in the code, or simply save the error code to a database for review.